# connecting to the database displays a mysqli_connect() function warning

Tags: php, mysql

My xampp was not working. I don't know why the Apache was not starting so I installed a wamp server. The localhost is accessed by port 8080 making it browseable as localhost:8080 but it is not working when I am typing.

Connecting to the database displays a mysqli_connect() function warning.

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:8080", "root", "", "social");//connection variable   
if(!$conn){ 

echo "Failed to connect! " . mysqli_connect_errno();
 } 

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO test VALUES('1', 'thing')");

?>
```

Comment: `localhost:8080` replace with `localhost` enough

Answer (score 2):

The port is not specified as a part of the host-argument, but rather as the 5th parameter. That being said, the default port for MySQL is 3306, while port 8080 is a HTTP alternative (default is 80).

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "social");
```

or if you want to specify a port, it'd be

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "social", 3306);
```

See the documentation and following links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

---

Also, you've got a slight typo in your code

```
if(!$conn){
```

is using the wrong variable-name (`$con` != `$conn`)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax: `mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname)`

```
 <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting mysqli modules from wamp server tray icon